# Align Vertical and Horizontal Align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a box VxH Center but I seem to be getting it just a bit off:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="logoWrapper">
                <div class="logo">Logo Here </div><!-- Logo End -->
            </div><!-- Logo Wrapper -->
    </header>
</div><!-- Wrapper End -->
```

**CSS:**

```
![#wrapper{
    width:955px;
    margin:auto;
}

html body{
    background:#F1FF29;
}

#logoWrapper{
    width:429px;
    height:179px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
.logo{
    display:block; 
    background:red;
    width:429px;
    height:179px;
}]
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ2ng.png

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341245/vertically-and-horizontally-aligning-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your margins for `#logoWrapper` to these values:

```
margin-left:-215px;
margin-top:-85px;
```

They need to be half the width and height of your logo.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwmDg/)

EDIT:

Also, I would suggest you put these 'reset' styles in:

```
html, body{
    background:#F1FF29;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```